# Unable to create subscription in razorpay nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, razorpay

I have a full-stack app (react native + firebase & firebase cloud functions as protected APIs), I'm trying to integrate `razorpay`, so for the frontend part i'm using `react-native-razorpay` and in firebase cloud function i'm using `razorpay` nodejs library.  The problem is that i'm unable to create a subscription, no logs are shown (even in firebase cloud function console), this is the only thing that gets logged: `Function execution took 1273 ms, finished with status: 'error'`, then I tried to run app on physical device, but again, the same response, in frontend app I catch the error and it says `CATCH ERROR: [Error: INTERNAL]`, below is the code:

Frontend:

```js
const onSubscribe = async () => {
  const creatSubscriptionCallable = functions().httpsCallable('createSubscription');
  let response = null
  try {
    response = await creatSubscriptionCallable({planId, planName});
    console.log('subscription response: ', response); // no log, straightaway goes to catch
    if (response.data.status === 'success') {
      const options = {
        subscription_id: response.data.subscription_id,
        amount: selectedPlan.item.amount,
        currency: selectedPlan.item.currency,
        key: 'xyz',
        recurring: true,
      } as CheckoutOptions;
      const razorpayResponse = await RazorpayCheckout.open(options);
      // ... payment verification steps and updating db
    }
  } catch {
    console.log('CATCH ERROR: ', error);
  }
}
```

Cloud function `createSubscription`:

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const Razorpay = require("razorpay");

export const createSubscription = functions.https.onCall(async(data,context) => {
  try {
    const { planId, planName } = data;
    const instance = new Razorpay({key_id:'',key_secret:''});
    const subscription = await instance.subscriptions.create({
      plan_id:planId,
      total_count:1,
      quantity:1,
      customer_notify:true,
    });
    console.log('subscription', subscription) // no log in console
    if (subscription.error) {
      return {
        status:'error',
        ...subscription.error,
      }
    } else {
      // saving subscription response details to firestore db
      return {
        status:'success',
        ...subscription,
      }
    }
  } catch {
    functions.logger.log(error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal","Something went wrong.");
  }
})
```

I think the reason i'm getting the `[Error: INTERNAL]` in frontend app is because my cloud function is throwing the `throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal","Something went wrong.");` i.e. after the `instance.subscriptions.create` method, the function straightaway going to catch block but not throwing any error(s).

Any help would be really appreciated!